# Python 3.4 Lottery Picker blowing past my if statement straight to else

Tags: python

This code works fine until I try to add "response" where user has to enter #"p" to generate one random number 6 times. I cant get it to recognize #variable "response" and "yournum" right from the first if statement.

Like I said it works fine with just the "yournum" variable - I just want

the user to hit "P" so it generates one line at a time.

```
import random
count = 0
response = 0
yournum = 0
print("Hello! Welcome to the Lottery Picker \n ")
print("Hit the letter P to pick each line or any other letter to quit ")
response = input()
while count < 6:
#response = 0
     if  yournum == 0 and response == "P":
         number = random.randint(1, 49)
         print("Your first number is: " + str(number))         
         count = count + 1
         yournum = yournum + 1      
     elif yournum == 1 and response == "p":
         number = random.randint(1, 49)
         print("Your second number is: " + str(number))         
         count = count + 1
         yournum = yournum + 1 
         print("Hit the letter P to another number ")
     #response = 0  
         response = input()        
     elif yournum == 2 and response == "p":
         number = random.randint(1, 49)
         print("Your third number is: " + str(number))         
         count = count + 1   
         yournum = yournum + 1
         print("Hit the letter P to another number ")
     #response = 0  
         response = input() 
     elif yournum == 3 and response == "p":
         number = random.randint(1, 49)
         print("Your fourth number is: " + str(number))         
         count = count + 1  
         yournum = yournum + 1
         print("Hit the letter P to another number ")
     #response = 0  
         response = input() 
     elif yournum == 4 and response == "p":
         number = random.randint(1, 49)
         print("Your fifth number is: " + str(number))         
         count = count + 1
         yournum = yournum + 1
         print("Hit the letter P to another number ")
     #response = 0  
         response = input() 
     elif yournum == 5 and response == "p":
         number = random.randint(1, 49)
         print("And your powerball number is: " + str(number))      
         count = count + 1
         print("Hit the letter P to another number ")
     #response = 0  
         response = input()          
     else:
         count = count + 1
         print("Something is wrong with the lottery picker - goodbye ")
```

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the request for the user to enter "P" and the line `response = input()` in your first if case. Also, your subsequent if statements check response against lowercase "p" instead of uppercase "P" like the first one. Assuming uppercase "P" is the correct one, your updated code is:

```
import random
count = 0
response = 0
yournum = 0
print("Hello! Welcome to the Lottery Picker \n ")
print("Hit the letter P to pick each line or any other letter to quit ")
response = input()
while count < 6:
#response = 0
     if  yournum == 0 and response == "P":
         number = random.randint(1, 49)
         print("Your first number is: " + str(number))         
         count = count + 1
         yournum = yournum + 1      
         print("Hit the letter P to another number ")
     #response = 0  
         response = input()        
     elif yournum == 1 and response == "P":
         number = random.randint(1, 49)
         print("Your second number is: " + str(number))         
         count = count + 1
         yournum = yournum + 1 
         print("Hit the letter P to another number ")
     #response = 0  
         response = input()        
     elif yournum == 2 and response == "P":
         number = random.randint(1, 49)
         print("Your third number is: " + str(number))         
         count = count + 1   
         yournum = yournum + 1
         print("Hit the letter P to another number ")
     #response = 0  
         response = input() 
     elif yournum == 3 and response == "P":
         number = random.randint(1, 49)
         print("Your fourth number is: " + str(number))         
         count = count + 1  
         yournum = yournum + 1
         print("Hit the letter P to another number ")
     #response = 0  
         response = input() 
     elif yournum == 4 and response == "P":
         number = random.randint(1, 49)
         print("Your fifth number is: " + str(number))         
         count = count + 1
         yournum = yournum + 1
         print("Hit the letter P to another number ")
     #response = 0  
         response = input() 
     elif yournum == 5 and response == "P":
         number = random.randint(1, 49)
         print("And your powerball number is: " + str(number))      
         count = count + 1
         print("Hit the letter P to another number ")
     #response = 0  
         response = input()          
     else:
         count = count + 1
         print("Something is wrong with the lottery picker - goodbye ")
```

Comment: Great! Can you mark this as the answer if it helped you get it to work? Thanks!